# how template POST parameter to view？

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

Hi~ o(*￣▽￣*)ブ ，I have a question about django template POST value to view.I have done this:
buttons：

```
for item in items
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" name="{{item.sn}}" value="parse" onclick="func1(this.name)"
<input type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" name="{{item.name}}" value="report" onclick="func2(this.name)
```

A button passes a unique value to a view's function.

```
views:
if request.method == 'POST':
    if btn1...?
        function1...
    if btn2...?
        function2...
```

and now I want to get the corresponding parameter when i click a button. and they are used separately for two functions. I used ajax to post parameters.but I don't know how to make btn1's parameters for function1, and btn2's parameters for function2. As the '?'  mark indicates.How to write the ajax code andthe view's '?' code

please and thanks!

Comment: try to write code instead of image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need some like this

jQuery

```
function func1(param){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/your/url/here/',
        data: {"button": "button1",
               "param": param,
                "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
            console.log("Post OK");
        }
    }); 
}
```

python

```
if request.is_ajax():
    button_name = request.POST.get('button', None)
    button_param = request.POST.get('param', None)
    if button_name == "button1":
        func_form_button1(param)
    elif button_name == "button2":
        func_form_button2(param)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used request.data.get can get the POST data, but request.POST.get just got nothing,how this happened?

Comment: Do you use django-rest-framework? It has Request object which has request.data. Hence  your data there is in request.data instead request.POST.
Standard django HttpRequest does not have request.data (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects)